# Ruby Geocoder.search by IP not returning city attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I am using `geocoder` gem to fetch coordinates by IP address. In my production environment it seems to be working but it's not returning city:

```
    city = request.location.city
```

returns `nil`. I have tried to search my IP through the `rails console` and returns:

```
[#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0xd282cd0 @data={"ip"=>"958.....", \
  "country_code"=>"NL", "country_name"=>"Netherlands", "region_code"=>"", \
  "region_name"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>"", "latitude"=>52.5, \
  "longitude"=>5.75, "metro_code"=>"", "area_code"=>""}, @cache_hit=nil>]
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?